# code formatting issue when upload my php(html) files on my server

Tags: php, code-formatting

I have using godaddy as server to host my website,

there is one problem when i upload my php files on my server, when my file is on localhost the formatting of code is perfect, but when i upload this file on server, there is blank new line is inserted after every line in the file and the new line is inserted every time when i download and upload the file.

below is the code of my php file with new lines

Thank you for any help

>

" />

```
/*



 * Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.



 */
```

Comment: are you uploading via ftp?  make sure your ftp program is uploading php files as ASCII not BINARY.

Comment: Are you developing on Windows?

Comment: thank you flauntster and Ben

i am using filezilla as ftp and files are on Auto mode and also i developing on Windows mode